# How to delay a Function without stoping or freezing the whole prog?

Tags: python, pygame

As said in the title, I'm working on a pygame project, and i want to make a delay but all the offered function are `pygame.time.delay()` or `pygame.time.wait()` and `sleep()` and all those 3 block the whole program when called.

To be more clear, i want a character to take damage every seconde when standing on lava, while having the right to run from it. But when the function goes out the program is bloqued and i can't do anything until his death.

```
def delay(y):
    starttime = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep (y - ((time.time() - starttime) % y))

def hurt(x):
    global Life
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play (Aie)
    Life -= x

if tilemap[PlayerPos[1]][PlayerPos[0]] == 4 and Life != 0:
    while tilemap[PlayerPos[1]][PlayerPos[0]] == 4 and Life != 0:
        delay(1)
        hurt(1)
        death()
```

( 4 stands for LAVA )

Comment: you can try the [sched](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html) module

Comment: `asyncio.sleep` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a condition including current time instead of using a delay, for example

```
if time.time()%1==0 and tilemap[PlayerPos[1]][PlayerPos[0]] == 4 and Life != 0:
        while tilemap[PlayerPos[1]][PlayerPos[0]] == 4 and Life != 0:
            hurt(1)
            death()
```

Comment: Why? What happens?